# Auto-generate numbers in Python

Tags: python

I've created this function:
generate_seat_number(movie_index,number_of_tickets)

and I need to auto generate seat numbers that start with 1 for movie 1 prefixed by M  so  like "M1-1","M1-2","M1-3"and so on but I'm not exactly sure how to do this.

would I use a for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Just try something like the following:

```
seat_numbers = ["M1-"+ str(i) for i in range(1, 101)]
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're using Python 3.6+, you can use [fstrings](https://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```
[f'M1-{i}' for i in range(1, 11)]
```

If you have a *functional* itch,

```
list(map(lambda i: f'M1-{i}', range(1, 11)))
```

Comment: 's answer will be faster since it is using list comprehensions.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question isn't super clear, I can give a few versions that might work, depending on what you are getting back.

Atomic call-case:

```
def generate_seat_number(idx, num):
  return "M{}-{}".format(idx, i)
```

List return to caller:

```
def generate_seat_number(idx, num):
  ret_list = []
  # 1 because humans don't start at 0
  # num+1 because range is not inclusive
  for i in range(1,num + 1):
    ret_list.append("M{}-{}".format(idx, i))
  return ret_list
```

Generator case:

```
def generate_seat_number(idx, num):
  for i in range(1, num+1):
    yield "M{}-{}".format(idx, i)
```

Hope this helps. Leave a comment if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

number_of_seats = 10

number_of_rows = 5

row = 0

for x in range (0, number_of_rows):

```
row += 1

seats_left = number_of_seats - 1

for x in range (0, number_of_seats):

    print("M" + str(row) + "-" + str(number_of_seats - seats_left))

    seats_left -= 1
```